# Why does my Redux reducer think my state is undefined?

Tags: redux, reducers

I believe I'm copying the Todo tutorial pretty much line for line, I am getting this error:

> Error: Reducer "addReport" returned undefined during initialization.
>   If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly
>   return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.

And here is my addReport reducer:

```
const addReport = (state = [], action) =>
{
  console.log(state)
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NEW_REPORT:
    return [...state,
      addReports(undefined, action)
    ]
    }
}
```

I added the logging statement and can verify that it returns an empty array. Even setting state to something like 1 will produce the same results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are missing the `default` of the switch case.

```
default: {
  return {
    ...state
  }
}
```

Redux won't play along like a nice kid if you forget to do it!

Or alternatively, you can explicitly return at the end the initial state:
`If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state.`

Comment: Interestingly this answer helped me because I was setting an object but returning simply "state" in my default. I wasn't aware you need to send a default state in the same format as the initial state. This doesn't appear to be the case if the initial state is an array or string etc.

Comment: For me, this as well as a syntax error (incomplete assignment line) caused the reducer to not load the state properly. Thanks!